# Expo start error on building JS bundle : type cast in HMRClient.js

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, expo, yarnpkg

### Issue :

I rencently encountered a blocking issue in my expo project (React Native).

**The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parenthesis**

I checked my code and didn't notice any change that would cause this problem.

When I type the instructions to start the expo building (shell) with MetroBundler, it always throws an error.

1. `expo start`
2. `Expo DevTools is running at http://localhost:19002`
    `Opening DevTools in the browser... (press shift-d to disable)`
    `Starting Metro Bundler`
3. **ERROR** :

```
Failed building JavaScript bundle.
SyntaxError: C:\xamppN\htdocs\mobile-new\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\HMRClient.js: The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parenthesis (284:31)

  282 | function flushEarlyLogs(client) {
  283 |   try {
> 284 |     pendingLogs.forEach(([level: LogLevel, data: Array<mixed>]) => {
      |                                ^
  285 |       HMRClient.log(level, data);
  286 |     });
  287 |   } finally {
```

**The type cast expression is expected to be wrapped with parenthesis**

### I tried :

- Editing the targeted file, it's inside a node module, *not
  very effective* if I have to yarn install later.
- Deleting all *node_modules* and installing again didn't worked
- Updating expo to last version, *didn't change anything, same error*

### More infos :

package.json :

```
 "dependencies": {
    "antd": "^3.23.2",
    "expo": "^39.0.0", 
    "expo-asset": "~8.2.0",
    "expo-av": "~8.6.0",
    "expo-barcode-scanner": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-cli": "^3.27.14",
    "expo-constants": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-localization": "~9.0.0",
    "expo-permissions": "~9.3.0",
    "expo-secure-store": "~9.2.0",
    "expo-updates": "~0.3.3",
    "expokit": "31.0.2",
    "moment": "^2.22.2",
    "node-forge": "^0.10.0",
    "npm": "^6.14.8",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-datetime-inputs": "^0.0.6",
    "react-mixin": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-39.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-create-bridge": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-dialog": "^5.6.0",
    "react-native-dialog-input": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~1.7.0",
    "react-native-imei": "^0.1.2",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^7.5.0",
    "react-native-pay-password": "^0.0.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~1.13.0",
    "react-native-sentry": "^0.43.2",
    "react-native-sha1": "^1.2.3",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.6",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.2.2",
    "react-select": "^3.0.4",
    "react-timer-mixin": "^0.13.4",
    "sentry-expo": "~2.0.0",
    "yarn": "^1.16.0"
```

Comment: I dropped expo, not worth my time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a conflict between `"yarn": "^1.16.0" and "npm": "^6.14.8"`.

You should choose **ONE** package manager and *avoid cross dependencies*.